# SSL _and_ www redirect with nginx

Tags: redirect, ssl, express, nginx

I got a cert for my server - `example.com` and opted not to sign it for `www.example.com` because I'm going to redirect all traffic from `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

Now, I've got an nginx redirect working for:

`http://example.com` → `https://example.com`

and

`http://www.example.com` → `https://example.com`

but I can't get this one to work:

`https://www.example.com` → `https://example.com`

What happens is nginx loads the site just fine *with* `www` in the address bar and then chrome throws a SSL warning because the cert being delivered is not signed for `www.example.com`, just `example.com`.

Here is my config. How can do I do this? Do I need to buy another cert and sign it for www.example.com instead?

```
upstream app_nodejs2 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3333;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen   443 ssl;
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate    /root/sslcert/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /root/sslcert/example.key;

    server_name example.com;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_nodejs2;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Comment: Regenerate your certificate with the www subdomain and it will sign both. You obviously are gonna need it.

Comment: How much more expensive is it to get a wildcard certification?  You might consider it if you think it'll come in handy in the near future.

Comment: I tried to regenerate it but Geotrust didn't allow. Turns out Name.com refunded me and I bought a new one and properly did it with www and no-www. Thanks everyone - lesson learned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a cert on the www address.

By using https your browser is demanding a secure connection before trusting to do what the server says. Your connection *isn't* secure so the browser won't send cookies, follow redirects, etc.

This is a good thing.

But it stinks for your cert budget.

If your CA lets you add www as a Subject Alternate Name you can handle both domains with one cert, which is convenient and has pretty broad support.

Comment: [expensive] Lesson learned - always take the free www. Thank you.